# what is the probability of B

Tags: probability, statistics

Let p(A) = 0.4 and p (AB) =0.7 what is p (B) if : 
1- A and B are independent 
2-  A and B are mutually exclusive

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definitions**

- $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$

*This is not true for $A$ and $B$ that are dependent.  The more general statement is $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B\mid A)$*

- $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive if and only if $A\cap B=\emptyset$ which would imply $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)$ and that $Pr(A\cap B)=0$.

*This is not usually true for $A$ and $B$ that are not mutually exclusive.  The more general statement is $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$*.

Your problem statement gives you the value of $Pr(A\cup B)$ and gives you the value of $Pr(A)$.  In each of the two parts, it also gives you information as to how you can simplify $Pr(A\cap B)$ into something more useful.

> your typo, $p(AB)=0.7$ can only make sense if it were to mean $Pr(A\cup B)=0.7$.  It could not have been $Pr(A\cap B)=0.7$ since $Pr(A\cap B)\leq Pr(A)$ by subadditivity.

Answer (score 0):

I think that $ p (AB) =0.7 $ should read $ p (A \cup B) =0.7 $

Hint:  $ p (A \cup B)=p(A)+p(B)-p(A \cap B)$.